# Differences Between Image Target-Size, Resizing Layer And UpSampling Layers?

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, keras, conv-neural-network

What are the differences between these three types of image up-scaling methods?
Define target-size with desired size in preprocessing images, implementing resizing layer and implementing upsampling layers?

Comment: Upsampling will repeat values in the smaller layer to reach the target size.
Resizing layers allow the user to specify how the pixels in the larger image are interpolated (e.g. bilinear, bicubic, etc.). I'm not sure what you are referring to by "Image Target-Size".  Is this a layer that instantiates an Image object from a tensor?

Comment: Absolutely not, I meant the target-size parameter which could have defined when import images by the ImageDataGenerator and its flow from directory as function, or even Image dataset from directory function.
But what you expressed about Resizing layer is the same strategy which is used in upsampling layer as i noticed in this link [UpSampling2D layer](https://keras.io/api/layers/reshaping_layers/up_sampling2d/)
Thanks for your explanation @MichaelSohnen

Comment: @SoroushMirzaei, the target-size parameter in ImageDataGenerator resizes all the images found.  As stated above by Michael Sohnen, to get the desired size, upsampling will repeat values in the smaller layer and with the resizing layers, the user can select how the pixels in the larger image are interpolated. Thank you!